# Vdebug vim never making connection

Tags: php, debugging, vim, plugins, xdebug

I'm trying to get debugging to work with Vdebug in VIM. Vdebug was installed with Vundle and whenever I try to open a connection, this is what I get:

`Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in 20 seconds...)
Connection to the debugger has been closed`

It doesn't even ever wait any amount of seconds.

Any idea what's going on here?

**Update:**
I've resolved this. I'm running PHP with FPM, which uses the same port (9000) as xdebug. Setting `xdebug.remote_port=10000` in the php.ini and then setting Vdebug port options `:let g:vdebug_options['port']=10000` in ViM fixed this for me. Now I can debug!

Comment: Have you read `:h VdebugTroubleshooting` and followed all the advice? Have you created an issue on the [Vdebug tracker](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug)?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRincker! The Troubleshooting section alerted me to where I should be looking.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @souparnomajumder Yep! Take a look at the update. Turns out I had a port clash...